# I want to reduce the time complexity to something lower than O(n^2)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, time-complexity

The time complexity of my solution is O(s<sup>2</sup>), where *s* is the size of the array.
I want to reduce the time complexity of this program: What is the better approach for this?

**Problem statement:**

Given an `array` of numbers of size `s` and variable `n`.

Find the number of occurrences where :

1. There should be a minimum of n elements from (0, i-1) that are
   lower to array[i].
2. There should be a minimum of n elements from
   (i+1, s-1) that is lower than array[i]

so basically for a given index, if we have a minimum of n elements to the left and right sides that are lesser than the element at the selected index, then it is a valid occurrence.

**Example:**

```
array = [1,2,8,5,3,4]
n = 2
```

**Answer:**

```
2

Explanation:

The possibilities are:

1) For array[2], we have array[0] and array[1] that is 2 elements less than array[2] towards its left side, to the right side we have 3 elements that are an array[3], array[4], array[5]

2) For array[3] we have array[0] and array[1] which are 2 elements less than array[3] towards its left side, to the right side we have 2 elements that are an array[4] and array[5].
```

**My code:**

```
int process(List<Integer> array, int n) {
    int s = array.size();
    List<Integer> left = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++) {
        int a = array.get(i);
        int count = 0;
        for(int j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            int b = array.get(j);
            if(b<a) {
                count++;
                if(count >= n) break;
            }
        }
        left.add(count);
    }
    
    List<Integer> right = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++) {
        int a = array.get(i);
        int count = 0;
        for(int j=i+1; j<s; j++) {
            int b = array.get(j);
            if(b<a) {
                count++;
                if(count >= n) break;
            }
        }
        right.add(count);
    }
    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<s; i++) {
        int a = left.get(i);
        int b= right.get(i);
        if(a >= n && b >= n) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: There should be a **minimum** of n elements: but you break on line 11. Does the min-match have to be sequential or can they be in any position to the left or right of the pivot?

Comment: Simple answer: Count inversions.

Comment: @pastaleg, it can be in any position.

Comment: Dont know who closed it but saw your response just now :) I have a solution for time complexity O(n*s)

Comment: @learner This works for only distinct elements in the array as of now. https://pastebin.com/XJrqfS2e  I have compared my answer with your brute force one and they should match.

Comment: @nice_dev, for this problem the input elements are distinct. For input `[1,3,2,5,4] and 1`, the expected output is 2. But the program you shared is giving me 1 as output. Can you please check this case also.

Comment: @learner Glad that the elements are distinct(lol!). Can you add this important aspect your question? Also, the algorithm I shared works fine on my machine as shown in this image https://imgur.com/a/FefuTg1